# What does Gear and Cog mean?

Tags: video-games, gears-of-war

In the game *Gears of War*, Soldiers are referred to as Gears while the military group they serve is referred to as the Cog.

My dad asked me the meaning of these when he was playing, I told them that most likely Gears was to refer to the soldiers as being Gears in the machine called War while Cog was the Acronym **C**oalition **O**f **G**ears since that's what they kinda were.

But I'm wondering if there is a canon source as to the meaning of Gears and Cogs in Gears of War.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few seconds with Google gave me [the Wikia page](http://gearsofwar.wikia.com/wiki/Coalition_of_Ordered_Governments) which says COG stands for **Coalition of Ordered Governments**.

Your theory on Gears was right - [Wikia](http://gearsofwar.wikia.com/wiki/Gear#cite_note-5) says:

> The term comes from the rotating machine which signifies the unity of the COG and the place of the Gear.
>
> *"I shall hold my place in the machine and acknowledge my place in the Coalition. I am a Gear."*
> — Oath of the COG

Comment: I'm always a bit iffy with Wikia sites at first unless someone points that they do update with canon material. i don't think i've heard the *Oath of the COG* but then again i got heaps of JRPGs to play and only get called in to beat RAM or Scorch and only know the basic premise of the first 3 games from moments watching my dad when i go past his room

Answer (score 3):

Might refer to the mechanical relationship of a smaller "cog" driving a larger "gear" - the cog provides the impetus, the gear provides the force.

[image]